# Python (Pandas) Add subtotal on each lvl of multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, subtotal

Assuming I have the following dataframe:

```
a       b       c      Sce1     Sce2    Sce3    Sce4    Sce5    Sc6
Animal  Ground  Dog    0.0      0.9     0.5     0.0     0.3     0.4  
Animal  Ground  Cat    0.6      0.5     0.3     0.5     1.0     0.2 
Animal  Air     Eagle  1.0      0.1     0.1     0.6     0.9     0.1 
Animal  Air     Owl    0.3      0.1     0.5     0.3     0.5     0.9     
Object  Metal   Car    0.3      0.3     0.8     0.6     0.5     0.6 
Object  Metal   Bike   0.5      0.1     0.4     0.7     0.4     0.2 
Object  Wood    Chair  0.9      0.6     0.1     0.9     0.2     0.8 
Object  Wood    Table  0.9      0.6     0.6     0.1     0.9     0.7
```

I want to create a MultiIndex, which will contain the sum of each lvl. The output will look like this:

```
a      b      c     Sce1    Sce2    Sce3    Sce4    Sce5    Sce6
Animal              1.9     1.6     1.4     1.3     2.7     1.6 
       Ground       0.6     1.4     0.8     0.5     1.3     0.6 
              Dog   0.0     0.9     0.5     0.0     0.3     0.4 
              Cat   0.6     0.5     0.3     0.5     1.0     0.2 
       Air          1.3     0.2     0.7     0.8     1.4     1.0 
              Eagle 1.0     0.1     0.1     0.6     0.9     0.1 
              Owl   0.3     0.1     0.5     0.3     0.5     0.9 
Object              2.6     1.6     1.8     2.3     2.0     2.3 
       Metal        0.8     0.3     1.1     1.3     0.9     0.8 
              Car   0.3     0.3     0.8     0.6     0.5     0.6 
              Bike  0.5     0.1     0.4     0.7     0.4     0.2 
       Wood         1.8     1.3     0.6     1.0     1.1     1.5 
              Chair 0.9     0.6     0.1     0.9     0.2     0.8 
              Table 0.9     0.6     0.6     0.1     0.9     0.7
```

At the moment I am using a loop to create three different dataframes on each level and then manipulate them on excel, as below. So I wanted to take this calculation in python if possible.

```
for i in range range(0,3):
    df = df.groupby(list(df.columns)[0:lvl], as_index=False).sum()
    return df
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that there is no default way of doing it in pandas. Note that you can produce the groups including their sums with multilevel index with `df.groupby(['a','b','c']).sum()`. However, this is lacking the total per group. You should look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29413496/pandas-computing-total-sum-on-each-multiindex-sublevel) which is very similar to your problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With some liberal use of `MAGIC`

```
pd.concat([
        df.assign(
            **{x: 'Total' for x in 'abc'[i:]}
        ).groupby(list('abc')).sum() for i in range(4)
    ]).sort_index()

                     Sce1  Sce2  Sce3  Sce4  Sce5  Sc6
a      b      c                                       
Animal Air    Eagle   1.0   0.1   0.1   0.6   0.9  0.1
              Owl     0.3   0.1   0.5   0.3   0.5  0.9
              Total   1.3   0.2   0.6   0.9   1.4  1.0
       Ground Cat     0.6   0.5   0.3   0.5   1.0  0.2
              Dog     0.0   0.9   0.5   0.0   0.3  0.4
              Total   0.6   1.4   0.8   0.5   1.3  0.6
       Total  Total   1.9   1.6   1.4   1.4   2.7  1.6
Object Metal  Bike    0.5   0.1   0.4   0.7   0.4  0.2
              Car     0.3   0.3   0.8   0.6   0.5  0.6
              Total   0.8   0.4   1.2   1.3   0.9  0.8
       Total  Total   2.6   1.6   1.9   2.3   2.0  2.3
       Wood   Chair   0.9   0.6   0.1   0.9   0.2  0.8
              Table   0.9   0.6   0.6   0.1   0.9  0.7
              Total   1.8   1.2   0.7   1.0   1.1  1.5
Total  Total  Total   4.5   3.2   3.3   3.7   4.7  3.9
```

---

I can get exactly what you asked for with

```
pd.concat([
        df.assign(
            **{x: '' for x in 'abc'[i:]}
        ).groupby(list('abc')).sum() for i in range(1, 4)
    ]).sort_index()

                     Sce1  Sce2  Sce3  Sce4  Sce5  Sc6
a      b      c                                       
Animal                1.9   1.6   1.4   1.4   2.7  1.6
       Air            1.3   0.2   0.6   0.9   1.4  1.0
              Eagle   1.0   0.1   0.1   0.6   0.9  0.1
              Owl     0.3   0.1   0.5   0.3   0.5  0.9
       Ground         0.6   1.4   0.8   0.5   1.3  0.6
              Cat     0.6   0.5   0.3   0.5   1.0  0.2
              Dog     0.0   0.9   0.5   0.0   0.3  0.4
Object                2.6   1.6   1.9   2.3   2.0  2.3
       Metal          0.8   0.4   1.2   1.3   0.9  0.8
              Bike    0.5   0.1   0.4   0.7   0.4  0.2
              Car     0.3   0.3   0.8   0.6   0.5  0.6
       Wood           1.8   1.2   0.7   1.0   1.1  1.5
              Chair   0.9   0.6   0.1   0.9   0.2  0.8
              Table   0.9   0.6   0.6   0.1   0.9  0.7
```

---

As for the how!  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Brilliant! @piRSquared

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you :-)

Comment: How is all_cols defined?

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @piRSquared Can you please let me know what the "**" after the df.assign do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pbou I'm unpacking the dictionary so that the key value pairs are passed as arguments to the assign method. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: Thx @Wen.  I saw you link it and wanted to let you know I appreciated it.

Comment: I love this, but it is now raising a FutureWarning: "'a' is both a column name and an index level.  Defaulting to column but this will raise an ambiguity error in a future version".  Do you have some updated magic?

Comment: It depends on your specific dataframe.  Use `pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis` to rename you index levels inline.  Or rename your columns.  It is complaining that your index level names can collide with the column names.  In the example I give, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Oh I see, i started with a frame that already had a multiindex [a,b,c] in place and replaced 'abc' above with df.index.names.  The OP didn't have a multiindex yet.

Comment: @rhaskett yes, you just had to call `reset_index` before calling `assign`

Comment: thanks for the tips! @piRSquared what if I want to stop the sum at a,b and exclude c's aggregation?

Comment: Hey @piRSquared, amazing! Just wondering: Could you provide also a column-wise version?

Comment: Thank you so much ! Note that you can use a list of columns names instead of 'abc'

Answer (score 1):

you need to do two `group by` to get subtotals at every level of aggregation. Then add those back in to the initial DF. Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570099/pandas-pivot-tables-row-subtotals).