# Transform pandas groupby result with subtotals to relative values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have come accross a [nice solution to insert subtotals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54248197/6658422) into a pandas groupby dataframe. However, now I would like to modify the result to show relative values with respect to the subtotals, instead of the absolute values.

This is the code to show the groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Category": np.random.choice(["Group A", "Group B"], 50),
        "Product": np.random.choice(["Product 1", "Product 2"], 50),
        "Units_Sold": np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(50)),
        "Date": np.random.choice(
            pd.date_range("1/1/2011", "03/31/2011", freq="D"), 50, replace=False
        ),
    }
)

iList = ["Category", "Product"]

pvt = pd.concat(
    [df.assign(**{x: "" for x in iList[i:]}).groupby(iList).sum() for i in range(1, 3)]
).sort_index()

print(pvt)
```

which results into

```
                    Units_Sold
Category Product              
Group A                   1170
         Product 1         434
         Product 2         736
Group B                    980
         Product 1         437
         Product 2         543
```

I have tried something along the lines

```
pvt.transform(lambda x: (round(x / x['Group A', ''],2)*100).astype(int).astype(str)+"%")
```

but obviously this only calculates values relative to the first row.

What I am looking for is

```
                    Units_Sold
Category Product              
Group A                   100%
         Product 1         37%
         Product 2         63%
Group B                   100%
         Product 1         45%
         Product 2         55%
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` with lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: (x / x.iloc[0]).mul(100).round(2).astype(int).astype(str)+"%"
df = pvt.groupby(level=0).apply(f)
print (df)
                   Units_Sold
Category Product             
Group A                  100%
         Product 1        49%
         Product 2        50%
Group B                  100%
         Product 1        52%
         Product 2        47%
```

Or use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
df = (pvt.div(pvt.groupby(level=0).transform('first'))
         .mul(100)
         .round(2)
         .astype(int)
         .astype(str)+"%")
print (df)

                   Units_Sold
Category Product             
Group A                  100%
         Product 1        43%
         Product 2        56%
Group B                  100%
         Product 1        58%
         Product 2        41%
```

Comment: thanks a lot, very nice solutions. I like the second even better than the first!

Comment: @divingTobi Kindly consider accepting this solution if it helped you so as to close this question. Thanks