# adding calculated columns in multiIndex dataframe pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
               star_rating          duration         
Date           20170829 20170830 20170829 20170830
genre                                           
Action         1038.1   1038.1  15917.0  16598.0
Adventure       595.0    595.0   9386.0  10113.0
Animation       490.7    490.7   5811.0   5989.0
Biography       596.9    596.9   9661.0  10002.0
Comedy         1211.7   1211.7  16616.0  16786.0

In[86]: df2.columns
Out[86]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['star_rating', 'duration'], [20170829, 20170830]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[None, 'Date'])
```

Hi all, I have the above table df2 and I would like to insert a difference column which will be a simple subtraction of 20170830 - 20170829.

```
            star_rating                     duration        
Date        20170829    20170830    Diff    20170829    20170830    Diff
genre                       
Action      1038.1      1038.1      0       15917       16598       681
Adventure   595         595         0       9386        10113       727
Animation   490.7       490.7       0       5811        5989        178
Biography   596.9       596.9       0       9661        10002       341
Comedy      1211.7      1211.7      0       16616       16786       170
```

it would be easy if the date was at the very top in which case I can use `df2['diff'] = df2[20170830] - df2[20170829]`.

I am new to multiIndex, so appreciate if anyone has any ideas to get me started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43238183/python-pandas-add-subtotal-on-each-lvl-of-multiindex-dataframe check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0,axis=1).diff().dropna(1)

df1.columns = df1.columns.set_levels(['diff','diff'],level=1)

df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.get_level_values(1).astype(str),level=1)

df_out = pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1).sort_index(1)
```

Output:

```
          duration                 star_rating              
Date      20170829 20170830   diff    20170829 20170830 diff
genre                                                       
Action     15917.0  16598.0  681.0      1038.1   1038.1  0.0
Adventure   9386.0  10113.0  727.0       595.0    595.0  0.0
Animation   5811.0   5989.0  178.0       490.7    490.7  0.0
Biography   9661.0  10002.0  341.0       596.9    596.9  0.0
Comedy     16616.0  16786.0  170.0      1211.7   1211.7  0.0
```